# Website that sells statistics

Tags: custom-field, database, security

I'm building a website that will  have statistics based on user activity on the website (online votes and views etc). People will have to pay to view those stats.

I am utilising wodpress features  such as custom fields and options to store the "numbers".

Now I'm thinking about the security of those numbers.

Will using my own custom database tables(or linking to another database) for storing the numbers instead of WordPress features provide more flexibility  in protecting the numbers?

When I say flexibility,  I mean are there more methods for more security compared to just using WordPress core tables. I also plan to create an app that uses the numbers in future.

Regards,

Comment: To ask a security question you first need to understand security concepts. I suggest you ask this kinds of questions at the security stack. FWIW DB structure has nothing to do with security 99.99% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Well to say that these custom fields are insecure in the wp core tables is to say that the usernames and passwords are also insecure, along with any private or password protected posts.

As long as you are not outputting these custom fields anywhere but a secure page for logged in, paid up users, no one could retrieve them without server side access to run a custom query.

Of course you should try to be security conscious when writing code for your site, by using data sanitisation and security methods such as nonces.